# Odoo v9 : In weekly timesheet form view only want current date entry edittable when adding a line

Tags: widget, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

how can I edit weekly_timesheet widget. The xml file calls the widget which is used to add line in the weekly timesheet.

I want user to only edit current date's time in the new or existing line.

How can I do so? Looks easy in XML but I don't know where from I can edit the widget.

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit widgets defined in templates, you create a new template and do something similar to this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="sales_team.SalesDashboard">
        <t t-jquery=".o_welcome_content" t-operation="replace">
            <div class="o_welcome_content">
                <h2>Bonjour!</h2>
                <h4>Une bonne journée commence par un pipeline de ventes bien organisé.</h4>
                <h4>Ajoutez-lui quelques opportunités!</h4>
                <a class="btn btn-primary o_dashboard_action" name="crm.action_your_pipeline">Mon pipeline</a>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Here I extend the SalesDashboard widget in the module sales_team. You just put the name of the tag (in my case it was `<t t-name="sales_team.SalesDashboard"`) on the `t-extend` part.

Then it's like inheritance of views, but instead of using `xpath` you use jQuery selectors (so like CSS selector then) and replace, after, before on `t-operation`. Here's a link on the subject : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/qweb.html#javascript